# Grails: how to reset a form in grails

Tags: grails, reset

I've already created the form and reset button for my application.

My **reset button** looks like this

```
<g:render template="/layouts/pageButtons" model="[type:'reset', value:'reset', reset:true]"/>
```

And my form is composed of textFields and radioButtons.

This is how I made my **radio button**:

```
<g:render template="/layouts/customElements" model="[type: 'radio', radioName: 'gender', radioLabels: ['Male','Female'], radioValues: ['M','F'], radioValue: employeeInstance?.gender]" />
```

I also have a portion in my page that shows the error messages if you have an invalid input, etc.

My question if, if I tried to click the existing reset button that I have, All fields will be affected except for the radioButton and the errorMessages. Which means that if I chose "Female button" it will not reset the value. And the error messages would remain in the page.

What can I do so that radio buttons will be affected by the reset and that error messages will be cleared?

Note: I need to use the render tag for reset and radio button, so please give me a solution that would use that as well. Thank you.

Comment: You could achieve both "Resetting radio button and clearing of error messages" by using jQuery or JavaScript. On click of reset button write the JavaScript code to reset the values to which you want.